# Cannot find app-root selector in Angular 6 app when deploying with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I followed all the steps required to deploy my Angular 6 app with firebase and I get a blank page and an error message:
"The selector "app-root" did not match any elements"

The steps I took to deploy:

1. ng build --prod
2. firebase init: here I change the public folder to dist/myprojectname, configure as a single page app, and to not override my index.html
3. firebase deploy

./dist/bookclub/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bookclub</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.33d366f8ea713aeef660.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.9f773b75ffcda6bb2a95.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.26ec44ceda27f0826914.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

./firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/bookclub",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why can't firebase find the app-root selector? It works fine when I serve the app with the angular cli.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no